# File in use while initiating file copy

Tags: c#

I am using the below line of code to copy the contents from remote directory to local cache, however i am getting a file in use exception while doing this.
Below is my code:

```
File.Copy(srcPath, srcPath.Replace(AppConfig.ConfigFolderLocation, LocalCachePath), true);
```

The LocalCachePath seems to be in use.

Entire code:

```
if (Directory.Exists(LocalCachePath))
            {
                foreach (var srcPath in Directory.GetFiles(AppConfig.ConfigFolderLocation))
                {
                    //Copy the file from sourcepath and place into mentioned target path, 
                    //Overwrite the file if same file is exist in target path
                    File.Copy(srcPath, srcPath.Replace(AppConfig.ConfigFolderLocation, LocalCachePath), true);


                }
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Directory Doesn't exists! Please create one");
```

Comment: That means that some process (probably your own process) has previously opened this file with exclusive access. If you need to be able to replace it, you would have to allow shared access to the file when opening it for the first time.

Comment: How do i provide the shared access to the file?

Comment: What api do you use to open it? Can you provide the code?

Comment: I have added the code above.

Comment: Most likely it is the destination where a copy of the file already exists and is locked and thus it is throwing error because a locked file cannot be overwritten.

Comment: so how do i unlock it?

Comment: Do you open this file in any other places in your code?

Comment: No,nowhere in the code.